# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in SessionsController#create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error in Rails 2.3.9 but not in 2.3.8. I didn't changed any code. Did I missed anything?

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in SessionsController#create ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

Thanks :)

Here are the added details.

```
Request

Parameters:

{"commit"=>"Login",
 "authenticity_token"=>"A9A4+sCsA/81FFoXJEUNziQYhgQ38pceGN2i7MUQbQY=",
 "password"=>"r3dp0rt"}
```

Here's the code in the application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery :secret => "r3dp0rtP@$$", :digest => "MD5" # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
```

Here's the code from my session create controller

```
  def create
    session[:password] = params[:password]
    flash[:notice] = "Sucessfully logged in"
    redirect_to "/login"
  end
```

and lastly here's the code from my simple login view

```
<div id="placeholder">
  <% form_tag :action => "create" do %>
    <p>
    <%= label_tag "This will enable administrative features for the site." %><br>
    <%= password_field_tag "password" %>
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
    <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug in the 2.3.9. It prevents to set the session ID when using an activerecord or memcache session store. See this [rails ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5581-session-cookie-not-sent-with-activerecord-or-memcache-store-in-rails-239). You can fix it by using the Mislav's patch at `http://gist.github.com/570149`. You'll have to create and paste the code in `config/initializers/sessions_patch.rb`. Or you can run the following command in your project root path:

```
wget http://gist.github.com/570149.txt -O config/initializers/sessions_patch.rb
```

Finally don't forget to restart your server (and a maybe issue a `rake db:sessions:clear`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to leave as a comment to the accepted answer so I will add this as an answer.  The patch does work but just be careful to name it `sessions_patch.rb` so it will be ordered alphabetically AFTER `session_store.rb`.  As I found out the hard way (by mistakenly naming the patch `session_patch.rb`, the order of the initializers matters and the patch won't work if it is loaded before your key and secret are set in `session_store.rb`.  Hopefully this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the browsing data of your browser? Most likely it's still sending the old AuthenticityToken.

Comment: Yup I did that but no luck :(